# Mono will not load mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linux, apache, mono

I have build and installed mono 3.0 on my server and now I can run asp.net sites on my server with framework 4.0. But I am not able to run MVC applications. This is what I wanted to achieve.

Whenever I upload an mvc project I get a runtime error. When I restart apache, I get the following error in my log:

```
[Sun Oct 06 18:19:51 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_mono/2.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.GetHash (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<string>) <0x000af>
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.RealMain (string[],bool,Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost,bool) <0x0015f>
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.RealMain (string[],bool,Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost,bool) <0xffffffff>
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.Main (string[]) <0x000f3>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_int_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4ad6a1]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf030) [0x7f3e05207030]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x7f3e04ea0475]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x180) [0x7f3e04ea36f0]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x62bb7d]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x62bcb6]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x5174b8]
    /usr/bin/mono(mono_class_get_full+0xe2) [0x5185f2]
    /usr/bin/mono(mono_class_from_name+0xeb) [0x51881b]
    /usr/bin/mono(mono_class_from_typeref+0x115) [0x5181d5]
    /usr/bin/mono(mono_class_get_full+0x145) [0x518655]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x5175d0]
    /usr/bin/mono(mono_class_get_full+0xe2) [0x5185f2]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x53f413]
    /usr/bin/mono(mono_get_method_full+0xe4) [0x53f594]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x46d741]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x424709]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4264a0]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x426f9d]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4af5ae]
    [0x41130186]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_asp.myvps.be
Root directory: /var/www/ASP.NET/
```

When I go to the web page I get an error saying my web.config is incorrect. But whatever I change in the web.config doesn't change the site. You can find this error here: http://asp.myvps.be/.

Is there anyone who can help me solve this?
Thankyou.